# Node.js implementation of open.epic single sign-on using HTTP GET?

Tags: node.js, encryption, single-sign-on

HTTP GET is one of the methods offered by open.epic for single sign-on. However, the documentation is a bit vague and doesn't give a good step-by-step process for decryption. 
According to their [documentation](https://open.epic.com/Launchpad/HttpGetSso) (note you'll have to create a login in order to access this link):

> We use 128-bit AES, with the CBC cipher mode and PKCS7 padding (this is equivalent to PKCS5 for our use). We use an empty IV. Additionally, we use Microsoft’s key derivation algorithm as outlined [in the remarks section here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379916(v=vs.85).aspx).

The remarks then outline an algorithm but nothing's done by example. Has anyone implemented this in node.js and could give a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took me a couple days, but I eventually came up with a node.js implementation. I'm using node version 4.7, with es2015 class syntax. I make use of the `node-crypto` library and only one external library -- `bitwise-xor`.
Also, one thing they don't tell you is the hashing algorithm required by the Microsoft derivation algorithm. I tried several before landing on sha1 as the correct algorithm.

You can find my implementation at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/emilyfeder/3ec62e86fa3aa1d4761f67c022f9fb72).

Comment: could you by chance provide an implementation example of your handler?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to publish as a node module or anything in the immediate future. The last 3 lines of the Gist show how to use it. You construct the handler with the secret you provided to epic and then run .decrypt() on the encrypted data param sent by epic. You can generate the param by visiting this link: https://open.epic.com/Launchpad/HttpGetSso (you have to log in first using any one of the account types listed).